# Error 403 Spotify API : ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am getting frustrated with this error :
`main.js:86 GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)`.

My JS code looks like this:

```
function getTopArtists(accessToken) {
  return fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
}
async function displayTopArtistsInConsole(profile) {
  const accessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;

  getTopArtists(accessToken)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch top artists");
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Top Artists:", data.items);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

I have tried debugging my code but I really cannot find any solution to my problem, neither by reading all the documentation on Spotify API. I am sure that my token is not expired at all because it can last up to 1 hour and I am running the code at the exact moment I open my HTML page. Could it have to do with the `async` keyword or something? I can provide the full code here thanks in advance :

```
const clientId = "50a6862feb5a4139af099a0ca99e267a";
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get("code");
let ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
if (!code) {
  document.getElementById("sign-in").addEventListener("click", () => {
    redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId);
  });
} else {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken(clientId, code).then();
  // fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks").then((res) => console.log(res));
  const profile = await fetchProfile(accessToken);
  populateUI(profile);
}

function generateCodeVerifier(length) {
  let text = "";
  let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier) {
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(codeVerifier);
  const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(digest)]))
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_")
    .replace(/=+$/, "");
}

export async function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId) {
  const verifier = generateCodeVerifier(128);
  const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);

  localStorage.setItem("verifier", verifier);

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("client_id", clientId);
  params.append("response_type", "code");
  params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
  params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
  params.append("code_challenge_method", "S256");
  params.append("code_challenge", challenge);

  document.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
}

export async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {
  const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("client_id", clientId);
  params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
  params.append("code", code);
  params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
  params.append("code_verifier", verifier);

  const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: params,
  });

  const { access_token } = await result.json();

  ACCESS_TOKEN = access_token;
  return access_token;
}

async function fetchProfile(token) {
  const result = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  });

  return await result.json();
}

function getTopArtists(accessToken) {
  return fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
}
async function displayTopArtistsInConsole(profile) {
  const accessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;

  getTopArtists(accessToken)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch top artists");
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Top Artists:", data.items);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

function populateUI(profile) {
  console.log(profile);

  const profileSection = document.createElement("section");
  profileSection.setAttribute("id", "profile");

  const h2 = document.createElement("h2");
  h2.innerHTML = 'Il tuo profilo <span id="displayName"></span>';
  profileSection.appendChild(h2);

  const avatarSpan = document.createElement("span");
  avatarSpan.setAttribute("id", "avatar");
  profileSection.appendChild(avatarSpan);

  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.id = "lista";

  const profileDataElements = [
    { label: "User ID", id: "id" },
    { label: "Email", id: "email" },
    { label: "Spotify URI", id: "uri", isLink: true },
    { label: "Link", id: "url", isLink: true },
    { label: "Profile Image", id: "imgUrl" },
  ];

  profileDataElements.forEach((data) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.setAttribute("id", data.id);
    li.textContent = `${data.label}: `;

    if (data.isLink) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("id", data.id);
      link.setAttribute("href", "#");
      li.appendChild(link);
    } else {
      li.appendChild(span);
    }

    ul.appendChild(li);
  });

  profileSection.appendChild(ul);

  document.body.appendChild(profileSection);

  document.getElementById("displayName").innerText = profile.display_name;
  if (profile.images[0]) {
    const profileImage = new Image(200, 200);
    profileImage.src = profile.images[0].url;
    document.getElementById("avatar").appendChild(profileImage);
    document.getElementById("imgUrl").innerText = profile.images[0].url;
  }
  document.getElementById("id").innerText = profile.id;
  document.getElementById("email").innerText = profile.email;
  document.getElementById("uri").innerText = profile.uri;
  document.getElementById("uri").setAttribute("href", profile.external_urls.spotify);
  document.getElementById("url").innerText = profile.href;
  document.getElementById("url").setAttribute("href", profile.href);

  document.getElementById("profile").style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById("nota").remove();
  document.getElementById("nota").remove();
  document.getElementById("sign-in").remove();
  displayTopArtistsInConsole(profile);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function () {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const code = params.get("code");

  if (code) {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(clientId, code);
    const profile = await fetchProfile(accessToken);
    populateUI(profile);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked for the token issued by the authentication service to be authorized for the scopes `user-read-private` and `user-read-email`.

If you review [the documentation for `/me/top/{type}`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-users-top-artists-and-tracks), you'll likely notice that the scope [`user-top-read`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/scopes#user-top-read) is required to retrieve this information.

You'll need to request this scope as part of your call to `/authorize` in your method `redirectToAuthCodeFlow`:

```
params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read");
```

Comment: Worked, thank you so much for the help and patience! :)